# Unable to upload Gunzip stream from GDrive to azure

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, azure-blob-storage, gunzip

- **Package Name**: "@azure/storage-blob"
- **Package Version**:  "12.9.0"

I am using node js and trying to upload png file from **gdrive** to **azure**. In order to achieve it. I am first reading file as stream from GDrive API.

when I perform read file, I get **Gunzip** stream. And when I use **uploadStream(stream)** it saves my file without any error.

Problem is that when I try to download it. I get my png file as **1KB(Original Size:266Kb**) which I am not able to open.

Am I doing something wrong?. Please help me.

```
const saveFromStream = async (inputStream, fileName, path) => {
  const filePath = getBlobName(fileName, path);
  const blobService = new BlockBlobClient(AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING, 
  AZURE_GAME_PORTAL_CONTAINER, filePath)
  const response = await blobService.uploadStream(inputStream,)
  return filePath;
}
```

below how gunzip(inputstream) look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. When you download the blob using the SDK, it will download the blob that is stored in your storage account. Since your blob is compressed, the downloaded file is also compressed.

You would need to decompress the file yourself once it is downloaded. SDK will not do that for you.

Comment: thanks for response, I am trying to download it via url. How to store it without compressing?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Also, please explain what you mean by "How to store it without compressing?"

Comment: sure I have edited my question with code. inputstream is Gunzip stream which I got from gdrive